# Trying to define a html code line in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to define $display as a html line. This is what I have so far.

```
    $display = '<input type="image" name="5more" value="5more" src="./pictures/fm/5more2.png" onmouseover="this.src='./pictures/fm/5more1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='./pictures/fm/5more2.png'">';
```

I keep getting this error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in results.php on line 15.

Please help me.

Comment: It's a string. Quote it.

Comment: Escape the quotes, for example `this.src=\'./pictures/fm/5more1.png\'"`.

Comment: @Kolink: the first and last apostrophes are not enough to quote it?

Comment: @pablofiumara They weren't there originally.

Answer (score 3):

```
$display = <<<EOF

<input type="image" name="5more" value="5more" src="./pictures/fm/5more2.png" onmouseover="this.src='./pictures/fm/5more1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='./pictures/fm/5more2.png'">

EOF;
```

Use the [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax and don't even worry about escaping (double) quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `'` in the string.

```
$display = '<input type="image" name="5more" value="5more" 
            src="./pictures/fm/5more2.png" 
            onmouseover="this.src=\'./pictures/fm/5more1.png\'" 
            onmouseout="this.src=\'./pictures/fm/5more2.png\'">';
```

Or use only `"` inside the string when you quote it with `'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the single quotes within. Try using this:

```
$display = '<input type="image" name="5more" value="5more" src="./pictures/fm/5more2.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'./pictures/fm/5more1.png\'" onmouseout="this.src=\'./pictures/fm/5more2.png\'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

A string declaration is encased with `'`.

> $display = '...content...';

This means that the beginning of the string starts with a `'` and ends with a `'`.

Your string includes a selection of double quotes `"` which is fine, however, your variable also includes...

> onmouseover="this.src='./pictures/fm/5more1.png'"
>   onmouseout="this.src='./pictures/fm/5more2.png'"

The single quotes `'` before and after the image declarations are what is causing the problem. The PHP compiler sees the first single quote `'` (just before the first image declaration) as the end of the string.

The solution to this problem is to escape the single quotes within the string. Just add a `\` just before each single quote. the single quotes will look like this `\'`.

Here is a correct declaration

```
$display = '<input type="image" name="5more" value="5more" src="./pictures/fm/5more2.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'./pictures/fm/5more1.png\'" onmouseout="this.src=\'./pictures/fm/5more2.png\'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes as mentionned above. But in terms of readability this design approach will save a few pains even if it's more wordy. Check if supported by your hosting configuration.

```
$urlOver = "./pictures/fm/5more1.png";
$urlOut = "./pictures/fm/5more2.png";

$onMouseover = "this.src='$urlOver'";
$onMouseout = "this.src='$urlOut'";

$display =
"<input type='image' name='5more' value='5more'
    src='$urlOut'
    onmouseover='$onMouseout'
    onmouseout='$onMouseout'>";
```

P.S: Curly brackets can be added as follows when between quotes ("..."): `{$onMouseout}`

Comment: Because of the unreplaced double quotes ? Have edited it. It is a valid approach though.

Comment: Would be interested to know a HTML purist's point of view on using single instead of double quotes :)

Comment: I always use single quotes for string literals in PHP.  Otherwise, the parser has to search for variables and what not within the string literal.  You're actually using that here.  I avoid it as it makes it nearly impossible to track down those variables with most syntax highlighting.  Plus, you'll want to wrap any arbitrary data with `htmlspecialchars()` when used in the context of HTML anyway.  Concatenation (for assignment) or a list (for echo) is the way to go, in my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

```
 $display = '<input type="image" name="5more" value="5more" 
 src="./pictures/fm/5more2.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'./pictures/fm/5more1.png\'"
 onmouseout="this.src=\'./pictures/fm/5more2.png\'">';
```

You can't frame an echo with single quotes and also use single quotes inside it. That breaks the frame and the output. However, if you escape the interior single quotes with `\`, you can get away with it. You could have also gotten away with using `addslashes` when echoing the `$display` variable, like this, IF and ONLY IF you change the interior single quotes to double quotes.

```
echo addslashes($display);
```

And your interior quotes would have automagically been escaped for you.

Comment: -1 for the `addslashes` comment. How would you define `$display` in the first place without escaping the quotes?

Comment: Good point... I guess they'd have to be changed to double quotes first.

Comment: But there are also double quotes in this string. The "difficulty" of this question is that the string contains both kinds of quotes.

Comment: That's the beauty of addslashes... it would figure out where they're needed.

Comment: Um... addslashes just blindly escapes everything it's been told to escape.

Comment: @DevlshOne It's a string literal.  You can't run `addslashes()` at parse time.